# Relation between angles of a triangle

Tags: trigonometry

In  $\Delta ABC$(with usual notations); $a = 2b$ and $\left| {A - B} \right| = \frac{\pi }{3}$  , then which of the following does not hold good ?

(1) $B+\frac{C}{2}=\pi$

(2) $2B=C$

(3) $A+\frac{3C}{2}=\pi$

(4) $A>C>B$

My approach is as follow

$\frac{a}{{\sin A}} = \frac{b}{{\sin B}} = 2R$

$\frac{{2b}}{{\sin A}} = \frac{b}{{\sin B}} \Rightarrow \frac{{\sin A}}{{\sin B}} = 2$

$A + B + C = \pi $ and $A - B = \frac{\pi }{3}orB - A = \frac{\pi }{3}$

First Case $A - B = \frac{\pi }{3}$, therefore $A = \frac{\pi }{3} + B$

$\frac{{\sin \left( {\frac{\pi }{3} + B} \right)}}{{\sin B}} = 2 \Rightarrow \frac{{\sin \frac{\pi }{3}\cos B - \cos \frac{\pi }{3}\sin B}}{{\sin B}} = 2 \Rightarrow \sin \frac{\pi }{3}\cot B - \cos \frac{\pi }{3} = 2$

$ \Rightarrow \sin \frac{\pi }{3}\cot B - \frac{1}{2} = 2 \Rightarrow \frac{{\sqrt 3 }}{2}\cot B = 2 + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{5}{2} \Rightarrow \cot B = \frac{5}{{\sqrt 3 }}$

Not able to proceed from here

Comment: (1) is never true for a nondegenerate (Euclidean) triangle as that would mean $A+\frac12C=0$.  Note that $c=\sqrt3b$ corresponds to the case $(A,C,B)=(\frac\pi2,\frac\pi3,\frac\pi6)$ and satisfies (2-4).